# cron jobs are stopped running

Tags: linux, cron

I have cron job that run every 5 minutes in my red hat machine.

2,17,32,47 * * * * root /usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/opt/swms/log/logrotate.status /opt/swms/etc/logrotate.d/syslog

After running for nearly 100 minutes, its stopped working.

```
May  7 16:14:00 localhost crond[14979]: (CRON) STARTUP (V5.0)
May  7 16:17:01 localhost crond[15358]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/opt/swms/log/logrotate.status /opt/swms/etc/logrotate.d/syslog)
May  7 16:32:01 localhost crond[17282]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/opt/swms/log/logrotate.status /opt/swms/etc/logrotate.d/syslog)
May  7 16:47:01 localhost crond[19121]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/opt/swms/log/logrotate.status /opt/swms/etc/logrotate.d/syslog)
May  7 17:01:01 localhost crond[20874]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
May  7 17:02:01 localhost crond[20996]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/opt/swms/log/logrotate.status /opt/swms/etc/logrotate.d/syslog)
May  7 17:17:01 localhost crond[22853]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/opt/swms/log/logrotate.status /opt/swms/etc/logrotate.d/syslog)
May  7 17:32:01 localhost crond[24691]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/opt/swms/log/logrotate.status /opt/swms/etc/logrotate.d/syslog)
May  7 17:47:01 localhost crond[26538]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/opt/swms/log/logrotate.status /opt/swms/etc/logrotate.d/syslog)
[root@localhost log]# date
Thu May  7 18:29:15 UTC 2015
```

I checked and Crond process is running. I have restarted syslog and crond services. Again facing the same issue after 1 hour.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that there is an error somewhere in your `/etc/crontab` file (or another crontab file, if you use others) which is preventing it from being parsed. You can check it with [chkcrontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chkcrontab).